# Using taken displayName to create a gallery app

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using the [Instantiate Application Template](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applicationTemplates/$%7BscimAppTemplateId%7D/instantiate) API to create a gallery app:

The body requires the following JSON:

```
{ displayName: 'customNameOfGalleryApp' }
```

If the displayName is already used, there is no indication in the response. We get a 201 (successfully created) status and unique IDs associated with the displayName.

Is there a way to NOT create a gallery app and issue an error if the displayName is already utilized?

Comment: Displayname is not a unique value and multiple gallery apps can have the same display name. The application ID is a unique field to differentiate and you need to check from your code side

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I can suggest at this stage is to check if an Application Template with that name already exists.

`GET /applicationTemplates?$filter=displayName eq '{appDisplayName}'`

Then fail the attempt in your client code.